# String replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, replace

Im developing a quiz system..

Let say i have this string..

```
$my_string = "The language i use is [ans]php[/ans]";
```

and the output is :

**The language i use is [input name='ans' id='ans' /]** //Textbox by the way

i use preg_replace function but no luck..

my code :

```
$string = 'The quick [j]brown[/j] fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '!\[j\]]';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '\[/j\]!';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';
$replacements[1] = '<input type="text" name="j_1" id="j_1" />';
$replacements[2] = '';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

The output was :

```
The quick []<input type="text" name="j_1" id="j_1" /> [/] fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Expectation:

```
The quick <input type="text" name="j_1" id="j_1" /> fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

really appreciate if you guys can help..

Thanks

Comment: Is that really the output you want?

Comment: Why not post your code so that we can try to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: the output was differ...

Comment: What is the expected output for `'The quick [j]brown[/j] fox jumped over the lazy dog.'` ?

Comment: Please describe what actually are you trying to achieve, these two examples really does not show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as your described.

`$string = 'The quick [j]brown[/j] fox jumped over the lazy dog.';`
`$string = preg_replace('/\[j\](.*)\[\/j\]/', '<input type="text" name="j_1" id="j_1" />', $string);`
`print $string;`

You can also access whatever is replaced between the tags by using `$1` in your replace string for the example above.

If you wanted to run another preg_replace to grab what the answer should be, you would do something like this:

`$string = 'The quick [j]brown[/j] fox jumped over the lazy dog.';`
`$answer = preg_replace('/(.*)\[j\](.*)\[\/j\](.*)/', '$2', $answer);`
`print $answer;`

The reason you use a `$2` is because it's the second match of the string. (Notice how there are three `(.*)`, each of those matches something. So, `$1` would equal `The quick`, `$2` would equal `brown`, and `$3` would equal `fox jumped over the lazy dog.`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_string = "The language i use is [ans]php[/ans] and bla bla [o]php[/o]";
$my_html = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\].*?\[\/.*?\]/msi','<input id="$1" name="$1"/>',$my_string);
echo $my_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$my_string = preg_replace('#\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[/\1\]#',
                          '<input type="text" name="\1_1" id="\1_1" />'
                          ,$my_string);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/Bh9tF)